# How to add icon of NavigationView drawer Android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer. I did an example of (NavigationView drawer) and it works great.But my problem is I need to know how I can add it.

Like this:

[image]

I have add it as ImageButton in activity bar_main but I don't need it like that.
As such, I have problems like the following:

[image]

I have seen many examples that the icon is not added in this way that is not an ImageButton. It's like come from the system without any ImageButton .So I need do that.

Now if I work like that , it will get overlapped with the search icon.When pressing the search button, the drawer icon should disappear.

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

static ImageButton  menuRight;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_m);

    
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        menuRight =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftRight);
        menuRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Politics) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Ploysity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
  

    public void onBackPressed() {

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

  
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement left navigation something like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout ...>
    <!--Main content-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    <!--Left navigation-->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView 
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_menu"
        ... />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For more information: [Material-Design-Navigation-View](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view)

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to change the icon, then you need to add this line:

```js
drawer.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_your_drawer_icon); //set your own
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_drawer_icon);
```